# Conditionally copying data from one sheet to multiple sheets using vba code

Tags: vba

Hi i have a code to copy data conditionally from one sheet to multiple sheets in a workbook. This code works as 1. before copying the data in to destination sheet it shall delete all the data in selected range in destination sheet. For me this part is working good but after deleting the data the code is not pasting data in destination sheet. Moreover i have set the code for non-empty string as "," which i don't know will work or not. This code is not giving any error so i am not able to sort this out. Code is as below:-

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cl As Range
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim RowEmpCrnt As Long
Dim RowUpdCrnt As Long
Dim WshtEmp As Worksheet

Set WshtEmp = Sheets("Employee Data")
Set Rng = WshtEmp.UsedRange 'the range to search ie the used range
str1 = "" 'string1 to look for should be empty
str2 = "Working" 'string2 to look for should be empty
Sheets("Updated").Range("B4:AV20000").Value = ""
RowUpdCrnt = 1
For Each Cl In Rng.Columns("AK").Rows
If Cl.Text = str1 Then
RowEmpCrnt = Cl.Row
If WshtEmp.Cells(RowEmpCrnt, "AV").Value = str2 Then
' In my test data, the "Working"s are in column AV and blank cells are in   column AK.  This For-Each only selects column AV.
' If both column "AK" and column "AV" contain the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet Updated
Cl.Range("B4:AV4").Copy Sheets("Updated").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
With WshtEmp.Rows(RowEmpCrnt)
Set Rng = WshtEmp.Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(100))      ' range A:Z
End With
Rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Updated").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
End If
End If
Next Cl


Set Rng = Sheets("Employee Data").UsedRange 'the range to search ie the used range
str1 = "," 'string1 to look for should be non empty
str2 = "Transferred" 'string2 to look for
Sheets("Transferred").Range("B4:AV20000").Value = ""
RowUpdCrnt = 1
For Each Cl In Rng.Columns("AK").Rows
If Cl.Text = str1 Then
RowEmpCrnt = Cl.Row
If WshtEmp.Cells(RowEmpCrnt, "AV").Value = str2 Then
' In my test data, the "Transferred"s are in column AV and blank cells are in column AK.  This For-Each only selects column AV.
' If both column "AK" and column "AV" contain the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet Transferred
Cl.Range("B4:AV4").Copy Sheets("Transferred").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
With WshtEmp.Rows(RowEmpCrnt)
Set Rng = WshtEmp.Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(100))      ' range A:Z
End With
Rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Transferred").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
End If
End If
Next Cl


Set Rng = Sheets("Employee Data").UsedRange 'the range to search ie the used range
str1 = "Executive" 'string1 to look for
str2 = "Working" 'string2 to look for
Sheets("Executive").Range("B4:AV20000").Value = ""
RowUpdCrnt = 1
For Each Cl In Rng.Columns("F").Rows
If Cl.Text = str1 Then
RowEmpCrnt = Cl.Row
If WshtEmp.Cells(RowEmpCrnt, "AV").Value = str2 Then
' In my test data, the "Executive"s are in column F and "Working"s are in column AV.  This For-Each only selects column AV.
' If both column "F" and column "AV" contain the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet Executive
Cl.Range("B4:AV4").Copy Sheets("Executive").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
With WshtEmp.Rows(RowEmpCrnt)
Set Rng = WshtEmp.Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(100))      ' range A:Z
End With
Rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Executive").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
End If
End If
Next Cl

Set Rng = Sheets("Employee Data").UsedRange 'the range to search ie the used range
str1 = "Supervisior" 'string1 to look for
str2 = "Working" 'string2 to look for
Sheets("Supervisior").Range("B4:AV20000").Value = ""
RowUpdCrnt = 1
For Each Cl In Rng.Columns("F").Rows
If Cl.Text = str1 Then
RowEmpCrnt = Cl.Row
If WshtEmp.Cells(RowEmpCrnt, "AV").Value = str2 Then
' In my test data, the "Supervisior"s are in column F and "Working"s are in column AV.  This For-Each only selects column AV.
' If both column "F" and column "AV" contain the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet Supervisior
Cl.Range("B4:AV4").Copy Sheets("Supervisior").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
With WshtEmp.Rows(RowEmpCrnt)
Set Rng = WshtEmp.Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(100))      ' range A:Z
End With
Rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Supervisior").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
End If
End If
Next Cl


Set Rng = Sheets("Employee Data").UsedRange 'the range to search ie the used range
str1 = "Workmen" 'string1 to look for
str2 = "Working" 'string2 to look for
Sheets("Workmen").Range("B4:AV20000").Value = ""
RowUpdCrnt = 1
For Each Cl In Rng.Columns("F").Rows
If Cl.Text = str1 Then
RowEmpCrnt = Cl.Row
If WshtEmp.Cells(RowEmpCrnt, "AV").Value = str2 Then
' In my test data, the "Workmen"s are in column F and "Working"s are in column AV.  This For-Each only selects column AV.
' If both column "F" and column "AV" contain the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet Supervisior
Cl.Range("B4:AV4").Copy Sheets("Workmen").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
With WshtEmp.Rows(RowEmpCrnt)
Set Rng = WshtEmp.Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(100))      ' range A:Z
End With
Rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Workmen").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
End If
End If
Next Cl

End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me.  Using ',' is okay.  Are you sure you spelt the search strings correctly?

Comment: now it is giving error copy method of range class failed       Cl.Range("B4:AV4").Copy Sheets("Updated").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)

Comment: You have 2 copies: the Cl.Range("B4:AV4") and the Rng.Copy.  The last of these two copies overwrites the previous copy with the entire working range.  Are you sure you want the second copy there?

Comment: No i want only selected range to be copied i.e. Cl.Range("B4:AV4").Copy Sheets("Updated").Range("B3").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)

Comment: i have used "," for non-empty cell str1 = ","   ('string1 to look for should be non empty) is it correct

Comment: Normally the way this would be done is str1<>""

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read every line of your code, but I think this will work for you, based on the description of your issue.

Create a new workbook for all unique values
Other examples and Example workbook

For more examples and a example workbook with the code below go to :
Copy records with the same value in a column to a new sheet or workbook

```
The range for the code example below looks like this
Column A : Header in A1 = Country, A2:A? = Country names
Column B : Header in B1 = Name, B2:B? = Names
Column C : Header in C1 = Gender, C2:C? = F or M
Column D : Header in D1 = Birthday, D2:D? = Dates
```

This example will create a new folder for you with a new workbook for every unique value in the first column of the range.The workbooks will be saved with the Unique value in the name into the newly created folder. It will also add a worksheet to your workbook named "RDBLogSheet" with hyperlinks to the newly created workbooks so it is easy to open the workbooks. Every time you run the macro it delete this worksheet first so the information is up to date.

Check if the information in these lines in the macro is correct before you run the macro

1: Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range. You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
Set My_Range = Range("A1:D" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))

2: Set the Filter field:This example filter on the first column in the range (change the field if needed). In this case the range starts in A so Field 1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
FieldNum = 1

3:Important:This macro call a function named LastRow
You find this function below the macro, copy this function together with the macro in a standard module

```
Sub Copy_To_Workbooks()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Long
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim foldername As String
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim ErrNum As Long

    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
    'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
    'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
    'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:D" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new workbook"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
    'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
    FieldNum = 1

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Set the file extension/format
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2013
        If ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat = 56 Then
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Else
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        End If
    End If

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Delete the sheet RDBLogSheet if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("RDBLogSheet").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Add worksheet to copy/Paste the unique list
    Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    ws2.Name = "RDBLogSheet"

    'Fill in the path\folder where you want the new folder with the files
    'you can use also this "C:\Users\Ron\test"
    MyPath = Application.DefaultFilePath

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'Create folder for the new files
    foldername = MyPath & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & "\"
    MkDir foldername

    With ws2
        'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
        My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("A3"), Unique:=True

        'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
        Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("A4:A" & Lrow)

            'Filter the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
             Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

            'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                     .Areas(1).Cells.Count
            On Error GoTo 0
            If CCount = 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                     & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                     & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
            Else
                'Add new workbook with one sheet
                Set WSNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

                'Copy/paste the visible data to the new workbook
                My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                With WSNew.Range("A1")
                    ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                    ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    .Select
                End With

                'Save the file in the new folder and close it
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                                    cell.Value & FileExtStr, FileFormatNum
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1

                    WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                     "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr, FileFormatNum

                    .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & _
                      "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr & """)"

                    .Cells(cell.Row, "A").Interior.Color = vbRed
                Else
                    .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = _
                    "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & cell.Value & FileExtStr & """)"
                End If

                WSNew.Parent.Close False
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If

            'Show all the data in the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

        Next cell
        .Cells(1, "A").Value = "Red cell: can't use the Unique name as file name"
        .Cells(1, "B").Value = "Created Files (Click on the link to open a file)"
        .Cells(3, "A").Value = "Unique Values"
        .Cells(3, "B").Value = "Full Path and File name"
        .Cells(3, "A").Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(3, "B").Font.Bold = True
        .Columns("A:B").AutoFit

    End With

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    If ErrNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
             & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
             & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    ws2.Select
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```